# Limesurvey encoding behaviour of other option

Tags: multiple-choice, limesurvey

I am using Limesurvey Version 1.92+ Build 120425. I am having a multiple choice question (List item with multiple possible answers) that has an open "other option": For example

- **Question7: Why do you like ice cream?**
- Because it´s sweet (Q71)
- Because my dog likes it too (Q72)
- Because other (please name other):_____(Q73)

In this case you expect Limesurvey to code the data as followed. Q71=1 or mising Q72=1 or missing Q73=1 or missing Q73other="Text".

For some reason Limesurvey just codes the "Text" into a variable but won´t code the corresponding 1 into a variable. Q73 won´t exist in an export of my survey data.

Is this a known problem?

UPDATE:
I compared Limesurvey behaviour of my version with the current available version of the official Limesurvey demo. While in the older version it was possible for a participant to select the other option and not write text into it in the latest version of Limesurvey the other option only gets checked if there is a text entry. The respondant seems to have no means of selecting the option otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could think of two solutions to this 'problem' (i do not expect Q73 to be 1 when text is entered in it). You could create one more subquestion, Q73, and always hide it with jQuery, then fill it if text field is getting filled, this way you will have a subquestion Q73=1/0 and Q73other='Text'/'Notext'. Another solution would be to simply create a short free text and move it up to your Q73other box.